# Where do apps like Yahoo Finance get their information and how can I create my own up to date database of stock trade information?

Tags: stock-markets

Are the trade prices for every stock publicly available in real time? How could I generate my own database of historical trade prices for every stock on the US market? How could I also update that database with realtime stock information?

Apps like Yahoo Finance and Schwab provide this information in real time, but I can't seem to sort the entire list of US stocks by the criteria of my choice. I want to access a sortable, live updating, table of every stock on the US market.

For instance, I would simply like to sort every stock by current market value. These apps do not seem to provide the complete list of stocks for sorting. They allow sorting smaller categories of stocks, where the companies have already been filtered down by some criteria.

Comment: You can simply make url requests to download the data you are interested in.  Yahoo is very Restful in that sense, or you can make a portfolio and scrape the data from a single URL request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the trade prices for every sick publicly available in real time?

The prices of all publicly traded stocks are available in real time.

> How could I generate my own database of historical trade prices for every stock on the US market? How could I also update that database with real time stock information?

You could collect historical data from Yahoo Finance (or similar) but given that there are about 7-1/2 thousand stocks trading, that could be a daunting task.  Plan B would be to subscribe to a data service.

Some brokers offer a DDE connection which enables Excel to be live in real time.  However, brokers tend to limit the number of quotes allowed.  Google offers intraday updating but I don't know if there is a quote limit.

> Apps like Yahoo Finance and Schwab provide this information in real time, but I can't seem to sort the entire list of US stocks by the criteria of my choice. I want to access a sortable, live updating, table of every stock on the US market.  For instance, I would simply like to sort every stock by current market value.

Finviz.com offers multiple free stock screeners with dozens of pre-set criteria.  However, it has delayed quotes.  They have subscriptions to greater content but I don't know specifics.  If value means price then FINVIZ can be sorted on that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are publicly available.

The exchanges allow you to access this data real-time *for money*.
Yahoo Finance et al pay them and run web servers that show them to the public, making their cost back by displaying ads.

I don't know the prices, but unless you run a business from it, I would excpect you cannot afford it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand: Are you saying you can pay a company for access to the data, but the data is also publicly available somewhere else? I'm interpreting 'publicly available' as free and posted information. Also, what actual entity is the US exchange? Is there a website? Is the exchange a single body?

Comment: Exchanges (New York Stock Exchange, for example) create the 'price' of a stock by matching up buy/sell orders. You can buy that information off them. In that sense, no, it is not publicly available from the exchange. Websites like Yahoo Finance buy that information, then show it to users for free, so in that sense, it is publicly available to you. Just be aware that anything you get off secondary sources like Yahoo is going to be significantly delayed (by several minutes), so it's no good for high-frequency trading.

Comment: For example, here's where you would go if you wanted to purchase real-time data directly from the NYSE: https://www.nyse.com/market-data/real-time

Comment: Could you update your answer with that link, and a comment about screeners? That summarizes everything I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: there is better link, where actual prices are shown. What these numbers mean is different question (pay model) https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/NYSE_Market_Data_Pricing.pdf and can be found here: https://www.marketsmedia.com/market-data-fees-an-overview/